# Dropbox API v2 Android - How to list files inside a sub-directory

Tags: dropbox-api

My AppFolder contains two sub-directories: Folder1, Folder2.

Each of the folders (Folder1, Folder2) has a bunch of files inside. I wanted to get a list of the files inside each of the sub-directories.

How do I check if Folder 1 for example contains files inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below:

```
result = client.files().listFolder("/Folder1");
System.out.println(result.getEntries().size()); // Should be != 0
```

The documentation is here :
https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html